# File error reading in Python

Tags: python

I am to new to python and want to process a data file with 6 columns and many rows. I got some problem with reading data from a text file. i am able to read first three columns but for column 4, this error pops up `-IndexError: list index out of range`. why do i get this error when there are 6 columns in my file. It is able to read first three and not more than that?

```
f = open('forceCoeffs.dat', 'r')
for line in f:
    data = line.split()
    frc={'time':data[0], 'Cm':data[1], 'Cd':data[2], 'Cl':data[3] }
    print  frc['time'], frc['Cm'], frc['Cd'], frc['Cl']

f.close()
```

Comment: have you printed data to see what it looks like?

Comment: Show us content of a forceCoeffs.dat file.

Comment: Are you sure there are *always* six columns? No blank lines (at the end?), or shorter lines?

Comment: i printed complete "data" and it prints nicely.,, moment i try to access column >=3, it gives that error

Comment: add what data looks like to your question

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your lines has less than 6 columns.
Then the line.split() does not produce a list with the required number of elements.

My suggestion:

Add a 'print line' so you can see at what line the error occurs.
Add a 'print len(data)' so you can see how many columns you have in your line.

```
for line in f:
  print line
  data = line.split()
  print len(data)
  frc={'time':data[0], 'Cm':data[1], 'Cd':data[2], 'Cl':data[3] }
  print  frc['time'], frc['Cm'], frc['Cd'], frc['Cl']
```

If no luck, post more details about the error and the contents of the file, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot danny, im getting the same error. i ran the code as provided by Mr. Keith and it works ...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access 4th column by data[3], but it may possible that some row don't have any data for column 4 so it gives error list index out of range.
Try below code:

```
f = open('forceCoeffs.dat', 'r')
for line in f:
    data = line.split()
    frc={'time':data[0] if data[0] else '', 'Cm':data[1] if data[1] else '', 'Cd':data[2] if data[2] else '', 'Cl':data[3] if data[3] else '' }
    print  frc['time'], frc['Cm'], frc['Cd'], frc['Cl']

f.close()
```

Comment: thanks a lot,,, ill try ur code,,, data is proper means no blank spaces in between

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's the case where not all of your data file lines are exactly what you expect. It may be some blank lines. Easiest thing to do is catch the exception and continue. This has the effect of ignoring bad lines.

```
f = open('forceCoeffs.dat', 'r')
for line in f:
    data = line.split()
    try:
        frc={'time':data[0], 'Cm':data[1], 'Cd':data[2], 'Cl':data[3] }
    except IndexError:
        continue
    print  frc['time'], frc['Cm'], frc['Cd'], frc['Cl']

f.close()
```

Comment: thanks a lot,, i ll try ur code, i checked there are no blank spaces in the datafile

Comment: ur code works perfectly, thanks a lot,,,, can u plz let me know why the problem was coming and why not in ur code.. thanks in adance,, ur feedback will help me learn python

Comment: i want to do some mathematical operations on the data, i tried reading the data as float by using say, Cm = float(data[1]) but it gives an error ValueError: could not convert string to float: Force
.... how to get it as float to do the mathematical operations -..thanks

Comment: kindly ignore my last comment as conversion to float prob has been sorted out ..thanks

Comment: i ran my original code without exception handling and i deleted the comment lines at the top of the file...and it worked ,,, the datafile was.dat format,, and i wonder that even if the lines were commented using '#', it was the main reason raising exceptions .. never saw such prob in matlab data handling